# jQuery and jQueryMobile: document ready/pageinit fires many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, document-ready, page-init

jQuery and jQueryMobile seem to load a page multiple times. However, for me it is essential that a certain initialization code is not executed more than once. I would expect that one of the following would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { ... });
```

or

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#myPage', function(e) { ... });
```

but they all fire many times-even if setup inside the section

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage"> ...
```

Even virginity variables do not work, i.e.

```
var virginity_f = true;
$(document).ready(function (e) {
   console.log("virginity.before: " + virginity_f);
   if( virginity_f == false ) return;
   virginity_f = false;
   console.log("virginity.after: " + virginity_f);
   ...
}
```

produces a console log something like:

```
virginity.before: true
virginity.after: false
virginity.before: true
virginity.after: false
```

**What is the solution for having a code fragment being executed exactly once in the environment of jQuery and jQueryMobile?**

Comment: Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fj5Q/1/)** executes only once. I've put your code in a fiddle, don't forget to check the console.